# Вывод изображений в слайдер

Tags: php, mysql

Для пробы создал на denwer мини сайт для пробы , вывел статьи из базы и так же создал слайдер на `owl-carousel`.
Циклом выводил `url` адреса изображений и через `include` подключил `slider.php` к `index.php`. Но изображения не выводятся, а выводится лишь самое первое. Сам эффект в слайдере работает; вся функциональность есть но, не выводятся *все(!)* изображения.

Прикладываю код :

```
$connection = mysql_connect( "localhost" , "maxim" , "123");
$db = mysql_select_db("test_db");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

if(!$connection || !$db)
{
    exit(mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM slider");

mysql_close();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"> 
       <img src="<?php echo $row['link']?>"/>
    </div>
</div> 
<?}?>
```

[image: скрин базы данных]`

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6Kd6/vV8UNULrt ссылка на копию db и самого сайта !
Как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: конечно спасибо за правку - но вопрос не в том как пост выглядит здесь , а в том как решить

Comment: От того, как вопрос выглядит зависит сколько людей решат уделить на него время. Если у вас нет времени позаботиться о том, чтобы отвечающим было удобно читать, то зачем им тратить на вас время? Учтите, что хороших вопросов здесь много и публикуются они часто.

Comment: убедили ! Но всё же как решить это ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо вывести контейнер карусели вне цикла.

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
<? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{?>
    <div class="item"> 
       <img src="<?php echo $row['link']?>"/>
    </div>
<?}?>
</div>
```

Иначе получается, что у Вас столько же каруселей, сколько картинок. А поскольку они все имеют одинаковый id - кажется, что это одна карусель.

Comment: а вы скачивали с майл .ру ? смотрели ?

Comment: Не понял. Что скачивал? Что Вы имеете ввиду? Я просто Ваш код посмотрел...

Comment: слава Богу ! там пошлятина - хорошо что не скачали - внизу есть ссылка на полную вёрстку и на sql - но хорошо что не скачали

Comment: так я и не скачивал :) Оно мне не надо... Я bootstrapовским слайдером пользуюсь...

Comment: я бутстрап вообще не люблю , мне он кажется через чур предсказуемым ! А скажи а ты не знаешь как кодировать изображение в base64 и потом выводить его ?

Comment: нет, не знаю. но это интересно. Вполне достойно отдельного вопроса ;)

Comment: считаешь можно задать такой вопрос ?

Comment: уверен. только деталей побольше :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485399/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-base64  вот - смотри и поправь как считаешь нужным